# learning the paython 3 hard way exercise 40

Tags: python

object oriented programming

i have applied the same code from exercise 40 learning the python3 hard way

```py
class Song(object):

    def _init_(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print(line)

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued",
                   "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
                       "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-2d6693ae7650> in <module>
     10 happy_bday = song(["Happy birthday to you",
     11                    "I don't want to get sued",
---> 12                    "So I'll stop right there"])
     13 
     14 bulls_on_parade = song(["They rally around the family",

TypeError: song() takes no arguments
```

Comment: You need **double** underscores on the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__
```

that is 2 `_` in both sides of the `init`.